# copy file to azure linux vm using pipeline task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, cloud, azure-pipelines, pipeline

i am trying to copy my artefact stored in blob storage to linux vm. I have found AzureFileCopy that works for windows vm but it was not working for linux vm because internally it use winRM command which only works in windows vm. can any one suggest who to achieve this using pipeline task.

```
- task: AzureFileCopy@4
  inputs:
    sourcePath: 
    azureSubscription: 
    destination: # Options: azureBlob, azureVMs
    storage: 
    #containerName: # Required when destination == AzureBlob
    #blobPrefix: # Optional
    #resourceGroup: # Required when destination == AzureVMs
    #resourceFilteringMethod: 'machineNames' # Optional. Options: machineNames, tags
    #machineNames: # Optional
    #vmsAdminUserName: # Required when destination == AzureVMs
    #vmsAdminPassword: # Required when destination == AzureVMs
    #targetPath: # Required when destination == AzureVMs
    #additionalArgumentsForBlobCopy: # Optional
    #additionalArgumentsForVMCopy: # Optional
    #enableCopyPrerequisites: false # Optional
    #copyFilesInParallel: true # Optional
    #cleanTargetBeforeCopy: false # Optional
    #skipCACheck: true # Optional
    #sasTokenTimeOutInMinutes: # Optional
```

Comment: Are your agents windows or Linux and by the way Azcopy for Linux was released a while back https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azcopy-on-linux-now-generally-availble/

Comment: my agent is linux

Answer (score 0):

For now there's no task available to copy contents from Blob storage to VM directly. (Even the Azure File Copy task is only supported to copy local files to VM.)

Assuming you have one Linux self-hosted agent, and a Target Linux VM:

1.You can use [Azure Powershell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell?view=azure-devops) to download the files from blob storage. Check **4c74356b41**'s answer from [how to download file from azure storage blob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55416414/10910450).

2.Then you can try [Copy Files Over SSH task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops) to copy the files to Linux VM.

Also, you can choose to install self-hosted agent in your Azure VM directly (Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129615/azure-pipelines-agent-on-azure-vm)). After that you can easily use Azure Powershell task to download the files in current machine.